# List of One-to-Many Entities shows temporary entity from another Activity

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have two activities. First activity shows list of notes. `Notes` themselves are lists. 
I use Android Architecture Components: ViewModel, LiveData; with Repository, Room, Dao, etc.
So, I make a method `getAllNotes()` in Dao, Repository and ViewModel like in google sample apps. In `onCreate` method of first activity I call `observe` and set adapter's content of a RecyclerView. And it works fine - it shows the list with `Note` titles.
Like that:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   //some code
   viewModel = obtainViewModel()
   viewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, Observer<List<Notes>> { notes ->
       recView.setNote(notes)
   }
}
```

Then I have a button that starts new Activity to create new `Note`. That note contains list of `Line`s which for now contains only string and foreign key.

```
data class Line {
    var id: Long? = null
    var note_id: Long? = null
    var payload: String? = null
}
```

`Note` and `Line` are one-to-many relation and they are connected by `id` of `Note` and foreign key `note_id` in `Line`.
(I don't write here all of the code, it works, trust me)

The problem is, that to insert `Lines` in database I firstly need to insert the parent `Note` and I do that. And it works almost OK too. But the liveData of the `getAllNotes()` from the first Activity gets notified by this insertion. And if the user, as a result, decides to delete all the lines and go back to the first activity even if I delete temporary `Note` entity from the database the list on the first Activity shows it for a moment because it gets deleted in a background with a small delay.

What I see as a solution:

1) Unsubscribe observers from livedata. I tried to do it in onStop method, but it gets called after the `onCreate` method of the second activity where the entity is being created, so the livedata already gets notified and observers are removed after temporary `Note` passed into the list.

2) Not use Room/SQLite as cache. Since this Note and Lines are not guaranteed to stay then and shouldn't be shown or inserted into a table. So, I can keep it all in properties of viewModel (i.e. in memory). But I see a lot of overhead work to save these entities through screen rotation, minimizing the app and all that stuff with saving state and restoring it.

3) Create two additional entities like CachedNote and CachedLine and corresponding tables, to work with it until I decide to persist the work, insert it into original tables and show it.

4) Add property to the Note entity like "visible" and add this parameter to Query, to make entity note shown, until I decide to persist the work. But there could be a lot of "updateNoteWithLines" every where.

What should I do? I didn't google anything useful.
I know it's like "What's the best way question", forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the `observe` in `onResume` and then call `removeObserver` in `onPause`, that way the `Activity` will not be updated, please look at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902457/4759619).