# View Model keeps creating instance of Live Data

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-viewmodel

I created the instance of View Model in `onCreate` method of an activity.

```
    ticketViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TicketViewModel.class);
```

Then i have a method, `AddTicket`, which uses `viewModel` to hit a service and on response from `viewModel` i dismiss loading animation.

```
 public void addTicket(View view){

     ticketViewModel.AddTicket(id).observe(this, response ->{
                        dismissLoadingAnimation();
    }
```

Now after adding a ticket, user can repress the `Add Ticket` button, and the `addTicket()` method will be called again.

but this time `observer` defined in ViewModel gets called 2 times, resulting in 2 network calls, and 2 `dismissLoadingAnimation` execution.

And if i keep pressing `addTicket` button, the number of executing observer defined inside `ViewModel` keep increases.

**This is my View Model code.**

```
public class TicketViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements IServiceResponse {

    MutableLiveData<String> mObservableResponse = new MutableLiveData<String>();


    public MutableLiveData AddTicket(String id){

        JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id",  id);

        NetworkUtility networkUtility= new NetworkUtility(this, ADD_TICKET);
        networkUtility.hitService(URL, jsonObject, RequestMethods.POST);

        return mObservableResponse;
    }


     @Override
        public void onServiceResponse(String response, String callType){

        if(serviceTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ADD_TICKET)){    
             mObservableResponse.setValue("success");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you didn't mean to put "sectionViewModel.getSeats" inside "sectionViewMode.getData", is that correct?

Comment: @AhmedAshrafGamal : First i call `sectionViewModel.getData`, when i get result from this method, i need to call `sectionViewModel.getSeats`

Comment: try Logging not debugging Log.i("test","test"); debugging inside threads sometimes gives wrong results.

Comment: are you sure about your service not calling onResponse twice??can you show that as well?

Answer (score 2):

The number of executing observer defined inside `ViewModel` keep increases becasue with every click You're registering new observers. You're not supposed to register observer with `onClick()` method.

You should do it in `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` or in `onViewCreated` method of your fragment. If You'll do that, there won't be a need to `removeObserver` when You'll finish work. `Lifecycle` mechanism will cover it for you.

But if you really want answer for you question, this is how you can do it

```
yourViewModel.yourList.removeObservers(this)
```

Passing `this` means passing your `Activity`, or there is a second way:

```
yourViewModel.yourList.removeObserver(observer)

val observer = object : Observer<YourObject> {
    override fun onChanged(t: YourObject?) {
        //todo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- The purpose of Viewmodel is to expose observables (Livedata)
- The purpose of View(Activity/Fragment) is to get these observables and observe them
- Whenever there is a change in these observables(Livedata) the change is automatically posted to the active subscribed owners(Activity/Fragment), so you need not remove them in onPause/onStop as it is not mandatory

I can suggest few changes to your code to solve the problem with the above mentioned pointers

**ViewModel**

```
public class TicketViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements IServiceResponse {

    MutableLiveData<String> mObservableResponse = new MutableLiveData<String>();

   public LiveData<String> getResponseLiveData(){
        return mObservableResponse;
        }

    public void AddTicket(String id){

        JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id",  id);

        NetworkUtility networkUtility= new NetworkUtility(this, ADD_TICKET);
        networkUtility.hitService(URL, jsonObject, RequestMethods.POST);

    }


     @Override
        public void onServiceResponse(String response, String callType){

        if(serviceTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ADD_TICKET)){    
             mObservableResponse.setValue("success");
        }
    }

}
```

**View**

```
    onCreate(){
    ticketViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TicketViewModel.class);
    observeForResponse();
    }

    private void observeForResponse(){
       ticketViewModel.getResponseLiveData().observe(this, response ->{
                            //do what has to be updated in UI
    }
    }

public void addTicket(View view){
     ticketViewModel.AddTicket(id);
    }
```

Hope this is of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call the `observe` once, I prefer to do it in `onResume` and then call `removeObserver` in `onPause`:

> Adds the given observer to the observers list

You keep adding listeners to the data so you get multiple callbacks.

**Edit:**
I took an existing code sample of mine for a `Fragment` and renamed everything (I hope), there's no example here for setting the data into the `ViewModel` but it should be `ticketViewModel.AddTicket(id);` in your case.

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;
    private MyRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private Observer<List<DatabaseObject>> dataObserver;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        initRecyclerView(rootView, getContext());
        initObservers();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(View rootView, Context context) {
        recyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerNoLastItemDecoration());
    }

    private void initObservers() {
        dataObserver = new Observer<List<DatabaseObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<DatabaseObject> data) {
                recyclerViewAdapter.setData(data);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initViewModel();
    }

    private void initViewModel() {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(MyViewModel.class);
            viewModel.getData().observe(activity, dataObserver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (viewModel != null) {
            viewModel.getData().removeObserver(dataObserver);
            viewModel = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show me the code on how to call `removeObserver` method?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. You could try to use [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

Or, in my, more complicated case, i had to use custom observer. It would looks like this:

```
public class CustomObserver implements Observer<YourType> {
    private MyViewModel mViewModel;

    public CustomObserver (){}

    public void setViewModel(MyViewModel model) {
        mViewModel = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable YourType object) {
        mViewModel.AddTicket(id).removeObserver(this); // removing previous 
        mmViewModel.refreshTickets(); // refreshing Data/UI
        // ... do the job here
        // in your case it`s: dismissLoadingAnimation();
    } 
}
```

And using it like:

```
public void addTicket(View view){

     ticketViewModel.AddTicket(id).observe(this, myCustomObserver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do some changes, i think we can handle it in much cleaner way

> LiveData is meant to be used to contain a property value of a view

---

**In ViewModel**

```
public class TicketViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements IServiceResponse {

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> showLoadingAnimationLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();

    public LiveData<Boolean> getShowLoadingAnimationLiveData(){
        return showLoadingAnimationLiveData;
    }

    public void addTicket(String id){

        JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id",  id);

        NetworkUtility networkUtility= new NetworkUtility(this, ADD_TICKET);
        networkUtility.hitService(URL, jsonObject, RequestMethods.POST);
        showLoadingAnimationLiveData.setValue(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onServiceResponse(String response, String callType){
        if(serviceTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ADD_TICKET)){    
            showLoadingAnimationLiveData.setValue(false);
        }
    }

}
```

---

**In 'onCreate' of your Activity/Fragment**

```
ticketViewModel.getShowLoadingAnimationLiveData().observe(this,showLoadingAnimation->{
    if(showLoadingAnimation != null && showLoadingAnimation){
        startLoadingAnimation();
    }else{
        dismissLoadingAnimation();
    }
})
```

---

**The main concept is to divide the responsibilities,**
Activity/Fragment doesn't need to know which process is going on, they only need to know what are the current properties/state of there child views.

We need to maintain a LiveData in ViewModels for each changing property/state depending on Views. ViewModel needs to handle the view states depending on whats happening.

Only responsibility the Activity/Fragment has about a process is to trigger it and forget and ViewModel needs handle everything(like informing Repositories to do the work and changing View Properties).

**In your Case,**
'addTicket' is a process about which Activity/Fragment doesn't need to know about there status.
The only responsibility of Activity/Fragment about that process is to trigger it.

ViewModel is one who needs to analyze the state of process(in-progress/success/failed) and give appropriate values to the LiveDatas to inform the respective Views